# NSScrollView with magnification other than 1.0 causes NSFocusRing to be offset

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

I have an `NSScrollView` with a variety of sub view types. Some are `NSTextViews`, some are `NSTextFields`, some are `NSButtons`, etc.

When I set the magnification of my `NSScrollView` to anything other than 1.0, the focus ring is not drawn over the proper location of the view.

For example, this is what it should look like (scaled at 1.0):

[image: Focus ring on <code>NSTextView</code> with <code>NSScrollView</code> at 1.0 magnification]

But with a 1.5 magnification, this is what it looks like:

[image: Focus ring on <code>NSTextView</code> with <code>NSScrollView</code> at 1.0 magnification]

Please note that on Stack Overflow, the images look about the same size, but in the actual screenshot, the 1.5 scaled image is larger. But you get the idea with the focus ring being offset.

To set the magnification, I am using the following code:

```
[self.scrollView setMagnification:zoomLevel]
```

So it's pretty simple code. The `NSTextView` obviously has its own `NSScrollView` surrounding it and that's actually where the focus ring is being draw of course. The same problem exists with just regular `NSTextFields` and `NSButtons` as you can see in these screenshots:

[image: NSTextField with focus ring and NSScrollView magnification at 1.5]

[image: NSButton with focus ring and NSScrollView magnification at 1.5]

You can see the button's focus ring is just a blue dot offset from where it should be.

At 1.0 magnification, it all looks normal.

If I use pinch to zoom, you can see the focus ring moving away from the field as the scrollview is zoomed.

Does anyone know what the proper way to use the `setMagnification` method of an `NSScrollView` should be? It seems like I should be able to just set the value. That does work, but I have these troubles with the focus rings not lining up.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

This is on Mac OS X 10.10.1, but it also happens on OS X 10.9.x. and also happened on OS X 10.10.

Comment: I suspect bug report + contact Apple's DTS for work-around.

Comment: @geowar yes, I guess that's my next step. Thanks.

Comment: @geowar bug report submitted (finally) rdar://21835630 since it's still happening in El Capitan beta 3.

Comment: @Tap Forms, I'm seeing the same thing. Please update if you hear back on the radar.. thanks!

Comment: fwiw I submitted a radar as well: 22299592

Comment: So far nothing. Thanks for filing another bug report on it.

Comment: It still seem to be an issue in macOS Catalina 10.15.1. Did anyone find a work around?

Comment: I ended up just drawing my own focus ring border around my fields to deal with this.